# How do you implement parameter aliases in an SQL databroker operation?

Tags: sql, aviarc

I have a table whose primary key is `claims_id`, but for legacy reasons I need to be able to look up records with either of the parameters `claims_id` or `claim_id`. How can I achieve this? I've used a pattern like the following for search queries before:

```sql
select...
 where (
         {$claims_id} is null
         or
         claims.claims_id = {$claims_id}
       )
       and
       (
         {$claim_id} is null
         or
         claims.claims_id = {$claim_id}
       )
```

...but this just doesn't seem quite right to me, as you could provide both parameters to the query, which doesn't make any sense. What's the correct way to achieve something like this?

These are large tables, and so if for someone reason neither parameter is specified, the query should return nothing.

**Update:** Noting that the database in question is DB2.

Comment: Are the parameters manually specified or are they being implied (with dataset-param, for example)?

Comment: You can use ISNULL(Column1, Column2) = ISNULL(Parameter1, Parameter2) in WHERE clause. But depends on your application;s logic

Comment: @TristanWilkinson manually. The operation needs to conform to the same interface as an analogous operation from another databroker, as I'm selecting the databroker dynamically.

Comment: Does the other databroker allow for both claims_id and claim_id parameters?

Comment: @TristanWilkinson it currently doesn't. Each parameter is supported by one of the databrokers. Either I could add support for both to each, or pick one to be used across both databrokers.

Comment: In this situation it seems like it would be better to pick one to use across both databrokers.

Comment: @TristanWilkinson That's the way I was going. You can still use `claims_id` in one, but both will support `claim_id`.

Comment: @Prasanna just noted in the question that it's a DB2 database, so then the equivalent function would be coalesce().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it isn't possible to adjust the broker so that it only allows for the one parameter name, then my recommendation is to have a pre-workflow for the operation which checks for the existence of the two parameters and adjusts them as necessary.

For the most simple example,

```xml
<workflow>
  <if test="not-equal" value1="{$parameters.claims_id}" value2="">
    <then>
      <set-field field="parameters.claim_id" value="{$parameters.claims_id}"/>
    </then>
  </if>
</workflow>
```

Then in the query you would only concern yourself with the claim_id parameter.

This would also allow situations where both parameters are provided to be dealt with or recorded in some manner.

Comment: +1 for that suggestion. A agree that it would be more appropriate way to deal with the problem. Since there is only 1 ID field in the table you are checking against then dealing with the parameters to the query should really be done in the application before you call that query.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually identify which one of the parameters has precedence and structure the query something similar to:

```
select...
 where (
            {$claims_id} is null
            and 
            (
                {$claim_id} is null
                or
                claims.claims_id = {$claim_id}
            )
        )
    or claims.claims_id = {$claims_id}
```

Here the **claims_id** checked as a primary option and then **claim_id** as secondary.

Comment: Looks like this would return *every* record if both parameters were null, which I'd like to avoid. Both parameters being null should either return no rows, or be an error, or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
select
.
.
 where coalesce({$claims_id},{$claim_id}) is null 
    or coalesce({$claims_id},{$claim_id}) = claim_id
```

Comment: This is looking pretty good, however what's the reason for the first half? If neither parameter was specified, wouldn't I then have an operation that's intended to return a single result returning every record?

Comment: Yes, the first half will return every record.